# reversing a string test cases

Tags: java, strings

I am trying to create a method that reverses a string that will handle every case. So far the cases I have come up with are

```
""
"abcdef"
"abbbba"
null
```

I haven't been able to handle these conditions however

escape characters

```
"\n"
"\t"
```

Not sure how to make `\n` or `\t` into a string

special characters such as

```
áe
```

code:

```
public static String reverseStr(String str) {
    if ( str == null ) {
          return null;
    }
    int len = str.length();
    if (len <= 0) {
        return "";
    }
    char[] strArr = new char[len];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        strArr[count] = str.charAt(i);
        count++;
    }
    return new String(strArr);
}
```

Comment: We can review your code, but questions about how you can add a new feature to your code is not the topic of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good overview of string reversal algorithms in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42985/36217). It should explain how special characters like é can be handled. I don't see what's your problem with "\n" and "\t". These are strings already.

Comment: Sorry I should have been a bit more specific. I wanted to handle inputs when `\n` is given by someone with out any programming experience whatsoever and expect `n\` to be returned not a newline.

Comment: How does that someone enter `\n`? Does he edit source code or provide input on CLI? If the former is true, leave a comment, otherwise I think his or her input will not be interpreted anyway.

Comment: @Liondancer If `\n` is a special case and should only return a normal `n`, that should be handled before reversing the string IMO. Be aware though that `\n` is just the programmatic way of writing ASCII number 10 (line feed).

Answer (score 0):

A little suggestion. Instead of

`if (len <= 0) {`

I'd write

`if (str.isEmpty()) {`

because it's more readable.

Available since Java 1.6.